# manual namespace in android studio

Tags: android-studio, namespaces

I'm trying to create a namespace for my useful methods. For example, to create an interface to work with a database. The interface should contain methods for insert, update and delete operations on the database. How to do this?

for example  create a new namespace  then use follow method  from that

```
public long putinfo(String arg_title,String arg_description,String arg_ctime,String arg_time)
{
    ContentValues var_contentvalues = new ContentValues();
    var_contentvalues.put(COL_TITLE,arg_title);
    var_contentvalues.put(COL_DESC,arg_description);
    var_contentvalues.put(COL_CURRENTTIME,arg_ctime);
    var_contentvalues.put(COL_TIME,arg_title);
    SQLiteDatabase var_sqllitedatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long id=var_sqllitedatabase.insert(TBL_NAME,null,var_contentvalues);
    return  id;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the Java/Kotlin that you have tried.

Comment: @MikePoole  i don't know how to do this

Comment: you can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link under your question and then clicking the `{ }` button on the toolbar.